# how to print previous string after selecting specific string python

Tags: python, regex, search, keyword, matching

I want to find word that appear before a keyword (specified and searched by me) and print out the result. I tried below code but it gives me after words not before...

```
    str = "Phone has better display, good speaker. Phone has average display"
    p1 = re.search(r"(display>=?)(.*)", str)
    if p1 is None:
       return None
    return p1.groups()
```

this code gives me

```
    , good speaker. Phone has average display
```

but i want only

```
    better,average
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead, with `findall` instead of `search`:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s+(?=display)')
>>> p.findall(str)
['better', 'average']
```

Comment: yes, it works. What is difference between  r'(\w+)\s+(?=display) & r'(\w+)\s*(?=display)

Comment: `\s+`: one or more whitespace characters, `\s*` zero or more whitespace characters. So the first will not match `neodisplay` (since there are no spaces before `display`) while the second will.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookahead assertion `?=`:

```
import re

str = "Phone has better display, good speaker. Phone has average display"
p1 = re.findall(r"(\w+)\s*(?=display)", str)
print(p1)
# ['better', 'average']
```

`\w` means a word character.